# Django ORM Query for Inner Join with Group By with different tables columns

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

I need to convert the below SQL query in Django ORM query:

```
select * from formslist a, files b  
    where b.fileId=a.fileId_id and formsListId 
    in (select max(d.formsListId) 
    from files c, formslist d 
    where c.fileId=d.fileId_id
    group by c.formNumber, d.state, d.product
);
```

Initially I have tried to convert this

```
select max(d.formsListId) 
    from files c, formslist d 
    where c.fileId=d.fileId_id
    group by c.formNumber, d.state, d.product
```

with this ORM query:

```
formsList.objects.select_related('fileId')
.annotate(Count('product'),Count('state'),Count('formNumber'))
```

Error :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'formNumber' into field. As it is not the 
field of formsList.
```

**I am not able to do Group By with different table columns while joining**

Below is my models:

```
class files(models.Model):
    fileId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    formName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    formFileName = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    formNumber = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class formsList(models.Model):
    formsListId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fileId = models.ForeignKey(files, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    effectiveDate = models.DateField()
    dateOfCreation = models.DateField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    formFilePath = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    formVersion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

**I have search about it but found only group by with same table columns**.

- Can anyone help me into this. I really appreciate.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh thanks I will try it but currently i need to convert this. can you help me with above problems.